# Deleting node group in EKS AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

Im new in AWS and EKS, trying to delete AWS EKS Node Group but I keep facing the health issue error below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeeT2.png)

Now the issue is I cannot delete the security group mentioned in the picture above also. Can anybody help please...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its really hectic to understand the whole AWS flow... Its been a week im trying to deploy by project on EKS, I have already created container and tested my application and created the image on ECR AWS as well. Now I dont know how to deploy the image from ECR to EKS cluster plus Now I cannot delete the node group which i created to test. First I want to delete this node group and create new. Thanks

Comment: how did you create the EKS cluster: eksctl tool, cloud formation template, aws cli, console?

Comment: @florin: thank you for you reply I already figured out... I created by console and I couldn't able to delete it because I had security groups tagged with it. First I deleted them then I deleted the nodes and cluster finally... Thank You!